# Can Eclipse log to syslog?

Tags: linux, eclipse, syslog

The log output from Eclipse ends up in a log file in the workspace, the configuration or sometimes the console. Is there some way to make Eclipse send this information to syslog instead?

Comment: Check this thread please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350027/log4j-and-syslogappender

Comment: I should have been more clear of course. I think the thread you are referring to would help me if I were a developer writing a plugin or similar. I'm asking from the perspective of a regular Eclipse user. Is there some preference setting or command line option or something that can make Eclipse log to syslog?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you want configuration: try looking at it from the other end. Can SysLog be configured to read from a file, if eclipse or an application output logs to that file?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but how about ...

./eclipse -consoleLog 2>&1 | logger