# What's wrong with my logback syslog appender?

Tags: java, logback, syslog

I'm trying to get a logback syslog appender working, and I've definitely got something misconfigured. I've created a [small sample project](https://github.com/pcsanwald/tmp) which I think should log to syslog, yet it doesn't.

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid. Here's the appender from [logback.xml](https://github.com/pcsanwald/tmp/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback.xml):

```
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>localhost</syslogHost>
    <facility>USER</facility>
    <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
</appender>
```

I've tried adding the port (514) explicitly, and, no joy. on both systems I've tried this on, I've verified syslog is receiving input using `logger "test message"` and then tailing either /var/log/messages or /var/log/system.log.

What do I need to change in order to get logback/slf4j logging to syslog?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350027/log4j-and-syslogappender ?

Comment: I did, but I'm logging to syslog on the same machine from node.js (bunyan-syslog) just fine, so this is very unlikely. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Not sure how node.js syslog logging works, but judging by `syslog.cc` I'd say it is using local logging, while logback/log4j use remote logging (hence the Host and Port). btw. tcpdumping loopback interface may tell if messages are getting sent from java ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code, the problem is the system config.
Using your provided test project, I was able to make the syslog appender work (Ubuntu 14.10).

Here are some steps:

- edit `/etc/syslog.conf` and ensure you have network syslog enabled:

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
# note that logback seems to use UDP, so this isn't strictly necessary.
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
```

- restart rsyslog (`service rsyslog restart`) if you change the config (reload doesn't work)
- check that syslog is listening with `lsof -i | grep syslog`

results:

[image]

Comment: nailed it. I'll award the bounty as soon as the system allows it (says I have to wait 22 hours). thanks for your help.

Comment: I only saw /etc/rsyslog.conf (ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @PaulSanwald is there a way to configure "RFC5424" pattern in syslog appender?